# What is the proper order of C# method parameter types (named, params, in, out, optional)?

Tags: c#, parameters, arguments

Let suppose a method uses all the parameter types (in, out, named, params, optional) in method.

What is the required order of param types for the compiler to be happy?

```
public static void test(out int num, in int num2, string last, string first="ABCD", params int [])
{
    // Method contents
}
```

Comment: `Params` argument must be specified at the end..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no defined order for the parameters (just param arrays need to in the last). As a senior developer we follow the following sequence:

1. Normal variables
2. Ref
3. Out
4. Default
5. Parameterized Arrays

Comment: And what if we want to use named variables ?

Comment: Named variables gives you freedom to pass the parameter in whatever order you want but while creating method we follow the order I stated. You can't be sure that person calling your method will use named variables or not,  so as a best practice you need to use some definite order.

Answer (score 0):

I like this order (only change OUT <=> IN)

```
public static void test(in int num2, out int num, string last, string first = "ABCD", params int[] l)
{
    //TODO LINES
}
```

1. readonly (in)
2. out
3. required
4. default values
5. params

First in (readonly)
later out
Required,
default values,

Answer (score -1):

Arguments passed to a method are always evaluated from left to right

From the C# 4.0 Language Specification:

> **7.5.1.2 Run-time evaluation of argument lists**
>
> During the run-time processing of a function member invocation (§7.5.4), the expressions or variable references of an argument list are evaluated in order, ***from left to right***, [...]

But its better to follow the below :

**Selection Funnel**

- Semantics
- Importance / Relevance
- Frequency of Use
- I/O Concerns

You can gain detailed explanation from [Stack exchange answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/101357)